# Failure to meet the Scalar Invariance model

Tags: r, manova, scale-invariance

I did an 6 group experiment and I ran the multi-group CFA and failed to meet the Scalar model.  I understand that the analysis should not compare means in that case but I can do MANOVA and SEM/Mediation Analysis in Macros right?

I also tried to sort things out with the Partial Measurement Invariance Testing Across Groups:https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/semTools/html/partialInvariance.html

I came back with the error saying "Error in partialInvariance(model3, "scalar", free = NULL, fix = NULL,  :
The elements named 'fit.loadings' and 'fit.intercepts' are needed in the 'fit' argument"

And below are the syntax I entered:

```
model3 <- 'fluency =~ Fluen1+Fluen2+Fluen3+Fluen4 
           transportation=~ Trans3+Trans9+Trans11
          attention =~ Attn1+ Attn2+ Attn4
          brandattitude= ~BrAtt1+BrAtt2+BrAtt3+BrAtt4+BrAtt5+BrAtt6+BrAtt7+BrAtt8+BrAtt9+BrAtt10+BrAtt11
          Luxury= ~Lux11+Lux12+Lux13+Lux14+Lux18
          transportability= ~STrans1+STrans2+STrans4+STrans5+STrans7+STrans9+STrans10+STrans11+STrans13+STrans16+STrans19+STrans20'
fit <- cfa(model3, data = MasterDataMay_7Final)        
summary(fit, standardized=TRUE, ci=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)

Scalar <-cfa(model3,
             data=MasterDataMay_7Final,
             group="Group",group.equal="loadings","intercepts" )
partialInvariance(model3, "scalar", free = NULL, fix = NULL, refgroup = 1,
                  poolvar = TRUE, p.adjust = "none", fbound = 2, return.fit = FALSE,
                  method = "satorra.bentler.2001")
```

How should I revise the syntax?

Many thanks for your help in advance